# Проигрывание анимации в не фоновом режиме

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Если добавить обычную анимацию `-webkit-animation` и открыть с ней сайт в фоновом режиме, она проиграется и когда человек откроет эту фоновую вкладку, он уже не увидит эту анимацию, так она прошла. Как сделать, чтобы она проигралась только если вкладка открыта?

Comment: @Soulism ну подождите, может ответит кто. Я специализируюсь на других вещах, и потому ответить не смогу при всем желании.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Вы не поверите..." Но это будет работать только в сафари или хроме. С другими браузерами как будете решать?

Вариантов решения несколько:

1. На ссылках пишите - НИКОГДА НЕ ОТКРЫВАЙТЕ САЙТ МОЕЙ СТУДИИ В ФОНЕ!!! :-)
2. Продумайте архитектуру - может эта анимация должна показываться не по открытию а по действию?
3. С помощью css есть наверное только вариант с -webkit-animation-delay или свойство это прикрепить к :hover - но тогда срабатывать будет только при наведении.
4. Воспользоватся js'om. С помощью js определить что есть активность на странице и запустить анимацию.

Comment: вот отличный ответ, но ховер не нужен, там именно анимация при открытии страницы. Единожды. Элемент дизайна)) 

Не знаете такой скрипт?